# WPF MVVM Data Binding - One Way?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am new to WPF but have an small understanding of MVVM, so far this is what I have implemented.

**UpdateTableView - View (Short snippet of larger user control)**

```
<UserContol.DataContext>
    <local:UpdateTableViewModel />
</UserContol.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding InputPath}"/>
    <TextBlock Content="Placeholder" />
</StackPanel>
```

**UpdateTableModel - Model**

```
public class UpdateTableModel : ObservableObject
{
    private string _inputPath;

    public string InputPath
    {
        get
        {
            return _inputPath;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _inputPath)
            {
                _inputPath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("InputPath");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ObservableObject**

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanaged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanaged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventArgs e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

**And an empty UpdateTableViewModel**

```
class UpdateTableViewModel : ObservableObject { }
```

My question is how would I use data binding so that as a user when I enter a inputPath in the text box, firstly whatever I type is store in the property _inputPath so I can use it in code behind and additionally be reflected in the text block.

I have done some research and found about one way and two way data binding and can't really work out what else I need to add for my desired functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `TextBox.Text` automatically binds `TwoWay`. It' the default behavior. So without specifying the `Binding.Mode` explicitly the text entered into the `TextBox` will be automatically sent to the binding source. In your case the input would be automatically sent to the `InputPath` property.

Comment: Why is your `UpdateTableViewModel` empty? It should containt the `InputPath` property.

Comment: @BionicCode. Thanks for your comments. UpdateTableViewModel is empty because I don't know what I need in there. I trying to find tutorials or examples but most are unclear. Thanks

Comment: What is the `UpdateTableModel` about, do you want to set it from the view model?

Comment: @BionicCode I have been trying to implement MVVM. In my understanding the view is the xaml, the viewModel exposes the model, and the model has the properties etc.. of the view? Is this incorrect?

Comment: No, that's almost correct. The view model doesn't expose the model. The view model is there to hide the model from the view. Let's say you have a database or file with user names and you want to display a list of them to the user. The model will expose the list of users to the view. The view model gets the items from the model e.g. by calling a method, which reads the users from e.g, a database or file. The view model acts as a presenter whose only purpose is to prepare and present data from the model to the view.

Comment: The view doesn't know the view. If you would bind the view to a view model property, which exposes the model, then the view is effectively binding to the model directly. And this you don't want. That's why you use  MVVM - to prevent the view from interacting with the model. I have updated the answer to show a simple view <--> view model --> model interaction.

Comment: In most scenarios the model doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Only the view model does this to allow dynamic data binding. I was wondering why  your `UpdateTableModel` implements this interface.

Comment: @BionicCode Thanks for the help and explanations. I think I understand what you saying. Reason for INotfiyPropertyChanged on model is because I download a example sln and was trying to understand the code rather than just going through a tutorial. This was in there although confused me slightly as other examples only have INotifyPropertyChanged  in the viewModel as they use it as a BaseViewModel class which all viewModel inherit from

Comment: Basically view is everything control or UI related. Not only XAML files but also .cs files or everything that contains controls or UI logic. Your view model is the model that exposes data and actions (`ICommand` properties) to the view for data binding (uni- or bi-directional). The model is everything else, that usually is the application logic, services, data persistence (database, file I/O).

Comment: Maybe read [Microsoft Docs: Patterns - WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern)  to get a better understanding. it is better to read official sources like Microsoft related or multiple "others", as many tutorials are not 100% correct about implementing the pattern.

Comment: Also don't use plain strings to raise the `ProeprtyChanged` events. Rather use `nameof` or the [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netframework-4.8). See [Microsoft Docs: `InotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netframework-4.8#examples) for a basic implementation that uses this attribute. This way you prevent errors as a result of misspelling or renaming.

Comment: @BionicCode Again thanks for all the pointers and help, much appreciated. I'll read upon on WPF on Microsoft Docs. I have managed to implement the fucnitonaility that I wanted as well so thanks again. In terms of using RelayCommand is that due to having an ICommand or button?

Comment: Yes, you bind an implementation of `ICommand` to the `ButtonBase.Command` property to execute a method of the view model. This way don't need to handle click events in the code-behind. This is the preferred way to execute view model methods from the view. Every button that derives from `ButtonBase` or generally every control that implements `ICommandSource` can execute commands. `RelayCommand` encapsulates the `ICommand` implementation, so that you have a single reusable command (alternatively you would have to implement a new class for every command).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view models must contain the properties you want to bind to.

Generally the `TextBox.Text` property automatically binds `TwoWay`. This is the default behavior. So, without specifying the `Binding.Mode` explicitly, the text entered into the `TextBox` will be automatically sent to the binding source. In your case the input would be automatically sent to the `InputPath` property.

**UpdateTableModel.cs**

```
public class UpdateTableModel
{
  public void SaveUserNameToFile(string filePath, string userName)
  {
    File.AppendAllText(filePath, userName, Encoding.UTF8);
  }
}
```

**UpdateTableViewModel.cs**
An implementation of `RelayCommand` can be found at
*Microsoft Docs: Patterns - WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern - [Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic)*

```
class UpdateTableViewModel : ObservableObject 
{ 
  private UpdateTableModel UpdateTableModel { get; }

  public ICommand SaveUserCommand => new RelayCommand(SaveUserName);

  private string _userName;
  public string UserName
  {
    get => _userName;
    set
    {
      if (value != _userName)
      {
        _userName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UserName));
      }
    }
  }

  private string _inputPath;
  public string InputPath
  {
    get => _inputPath;
    set
    {
      if (value != _inputPath)
      {
        _inputPath = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InputPath));
      }
    }
  }

  public UpdateTableViewModel()
  {
    this.UpdateTableModel = new UpdateTableModel();
  }

  // Alternative constructor
  public UpdateTableViewModel(UpdateTableModel updateTableModel)
  {
    this.UpdateTableModel = updateTableModel;
  }

  private void SaveUserName(object param)
  {
    // Pass the data to the model
    this.UpdateTableModel.SaveUserNameToFile(this.InputPath, this.UserName);
  }
}
```

**UpdateTableView.xaml**

```
<UserControl>
  <UserContol.DataContext>
    <local:UpdateTableViewModel />
  </UserContol.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding UserName}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding InputPath}" />
    <Button Command="{Binding SaveUserCommand}" 
            Content="Save to File" />
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```